# Inner join in Django 1.9

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have these two models:

```
class ModelInteractions(models.Model):
    id1 = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id2 = models.IntegerField()
    comm = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        unique_together = (('id1', 'id2'),)


class Models(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

and I want to select also `comm`. In my view, I use the following code to get data from `Models`:

```
condition = Q(name__icontains=names[0])
for name in names[1:]:
    condition &= Q(name__icontains=name)
# ↓↓↓ this line is for what I need but it doesn't work
condition &= Q(ModelInteractions__id2=id)

models = Models.objects.filter(condition)
```

`id` is received on request (`def details(request, id):`).

I need to select `comm` from `ModelInteractions` where `id2` = `id` (id received on request).

Current code returns:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'ModelInteractions' into field. Choices are: id, name
```

Comment: you cannot do it like this in django, you need to have relationship with foreignkey, then you can  use it or else use raw query if you dont want to mention relations

Comment: Can you, please, show an example for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ModelInteractions(models.Model):
    id1 = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id2 = models.IntegerField()
    comm = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        unique_together = (('id1', 'id2'),)


class Models(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    interaction= models.ForeignKey(ModelInteractions,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

make your models like this, then makemigrations and migrate

then run the same query till here

```
condition = Q(name__icontains=names[0])
for name in names[1:]:
    condition &= Q(name__icontains=name)
```

then change this line

```
condition &= Q(interaction__id2=id)
```

then

```
models = Models.objects.filter(condition)
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I provide a default value? I get this `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "interaction_id" contains null values` when migrating.

Comment: you can, as for the old data in the table, you have blank value, you can drop the database and create a new one and migrate, if you dont need the old data, or else give default=1